# How to synchronize OpenLDAP user to AD LDS or AD with SHA password

Tags: hash, active-directory, openldap, adlds, phpldapadmin

We now use OpenLDAP to manage our users. However, there are some applications that can only connect to AD or AD LDS, such as IBM DOORS. We write a synchronization module with PHP to synchronize OpenLDAP users to AD. However, we found that we cannot synchronize the user password.

The user password in OpenLDAP is in SHA hashed and we can get the SHA hashed value. We hope to write this SHA hashed value to AD and the user can use the same password in OpenLDAP to bind to AD. And it would be more nice if this can be achieved in AD LDS. If anyone have any ideas about how to do this, please help us. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Define "we found that we cannot synchronize the user password".